# What is non-linear analysis?

Tags: soft-question

Can anybody tell me what non-linear analysis is? I have no idea. I am not getting wikipedia page, may be because of my bad searching habit. I am seeing a lot of research materials published in different mathematics journals.

I want to know the followings

1. Idea about the subject.
2. The other fields of mathematics which are required to starting study nonlinear analysis.
3. Application of nonlinear analysis in different brunches of science as well as mathematics.
4. Books reference to this subject.

I am going to apply in a PhD programme in some Indian University who are looking for scholars who are interested to work in this field.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-2-002-finite-element-procedures-for-solids-and-structures-spring-2010/nonlinear/ ? I also think you need to be a little more specific as to what area of nonlinear analysis because it can apply to many areas like FEM, Data Analysis, Time Series ...

Comment: I always thought analysis was very much nonlinear...

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you for giving me a helpful link. Please write it as an answer.

Comment: You might want to look at these sites for materials from your question: https://www.math.cmu.edu/cna/index.php, http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/cas/courses.d/NFEM.d/, http://www.nafems.org/events/nafems/2013/non-linear_fe_analysis_oct/, http://www.lusas.com/support/trainingcourse_nonlinear.html, http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Nonlinear_finite_elements, http://www.mscsoftware.com/application/nonlinear-analysis Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you very much. I hope I can submit a research proposal at present.

Comment: @Samprity: You are very welcome and great luck in your endeavors!